# Create electrum server with bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, full-node, bluewallet

I installed bitcoin core pruned node today on my laptop. I want to connect my blue wallet to my bitcoin node I created with bitcoin core. I read somewhere that for it to happen I need to have electrum server. So can someone explain how to create electrum server with my bitcoin core to connect to my blue wallet

Answer (score 1):

You need to install an Electrum server from outside of the Bitcoin Core software, there are various options: [Electrum Personal Server](https://github.com/chris-belcher/electrum-personal-server), [electrs](https://github.com/romanz/electrs), [ElectrumX](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrumx).

Alternatively you may be interested in [Bitcoin Wallet Tracker](https://github.com/bwt-dev/bwt) (BWT) which offers more options including a one click setup and Electrum wallet plugin option.

BlueWallet also provides [some Electrum servers](https://github.com/BlueWallet/BlueWallet/wiki/Electrum-servers-pool) to connect to if you want to use those.

Comment: How can I connect my blue wallet to my bitcoin core prune node?

Answer (score -2):

I struggled a lot to connect Electrum <-> EPS <-> Bitcoin Core, especially 'cause of the .cookie path, the certificat problem, the configuration of config.ini and the 127.0.0.1 cookie file of Electrum.

There aren't lots of helps on Windows. That's why i've decided yesterday to do a full-explained tutorial on youtube, which explains everything: how to do, how to resolve all configuration problems, etc...
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxiH8hG9G-4&ab_channel=ProfEduStream
It's in french, but you can add subtitles on your own langage.

Hope it gonna help the community.

Bye

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Since your link also is to your own content, it's generally advised to disclose that. However please avoid excessively promoting your own content here, this is not an advertisement platform.